# Why is my computer crashing running the following code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My computer crashes using the folowing code:

```
    import itertools

    list_Abecedario= ["a", "b", "c", "d",
             "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", 
             "p", "q", "r", "s", "t",
             "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

    for i in range(1, len(list_Abecedario)+1):
         for x in list(itertools.permutations(list_Abecedario, i)):
         aux = ''.join(x)
         print(aux)
```

The output is correct, but when he comes to 6 characters the computer starts to be very slowly and crashes. I can't understand this slow and crash. In a first look i would say that was because of memory, but i have 12gb ram and my computer isn't keeping the data anywhere.

Why is the computer crashing?

Computer specs:
Processor: i7-5500u 2.4-3.00 Ghz
Ram: 12
disk: 120 SDD + 1T
graphic: r7 m260

Comment: This loop would go on forever would it not? it obviously can't cope with infinite results

Comment: First loop get the len of the output should be. The second loop does every single permutation possible, for example: i = 2, the output would be like a ,b ,c,d,e,f,g,h,i...aa,ab,ac,ad,...,ba,bb,bc,bd,be,...zx,zy,zz, then goes to 3 characters.

Comment: According to [math](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/permutations.php) `P(26, 6) = 165765600`.

Comment: @L_Church no this is not an infinite loop.

Comment: still a lot. lol

Comment: Why are you calling `list` on your `itertools.permutations` object? Even with `i == 6`, this would require a list of `165765600*8*1e-9 == 1.326` gigabytes, and at `i==7`, it would require a list that uses `3315312000*8*1e-9 == 26.5` gigabytes.

Comment: It has a response right below, but thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
for x in list(itertools.permutations(list_Abecedario, i)):
```

does store all the possible permutations (and there might be many) in memory, so yes your computer **is** "keeping the data" somewhere. FWIW making a list of those permutations only to iterate over this list is totally defeats the whole point of itertools, which is to use lazy iteration (hence saving memory). So the solution here is simple: just iterate over `itertools.permutations`:

```
for x in itertools.permutations(list_Abecedario, i):
```

EDIT: note that given the huge number of permutations, even if you don't hit another memory limit, your program will take a *very* long time to finish.

Comment: That said, even with lazy iterations the sun will explode before the program ends.

Comment: @bereal possibly but that's another problem xD

Comment: @bereal yeah, by my calculation, the whole loop will require about `1.096e+27` iterations. Doing an empty loop (just a `pass`) with 10**8 iterations on my machine took about 2.15 seconds. Extrapolating forward, I get `t*10**(27-8) == 2.15**19`, which wolfram-alpha says is about 50 times the age of the universe...

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating all the possibile 6 elements permutations, starting from all the possible letters. This puts a lot of strain on your processor. The slow part of your program is

```
itertools.permutations(list_Abecedario, i)
```

With 6 elements, using the alphabet, the total permutations are 165'765'600. And I got this number only with the [formula](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/permutations.php), your pc actually needs to calculate every possible permutation by placing the elements together every time.

Comment: Actually, `itertools.permutations(list_Abecedario, i)` takes almost no time at all...

Comment: So it is impossible to my computer get this done right?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga actually you are correct. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @JoaoPedroLopesMendes it's not impossible, it's just very slow. You may try to circumvent this issue by modifying how your program works or by changing your objective